# qsort not properly sorting array of pointers to struct in C

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, pass-by-reference, qsort

I am trying to use qsort to sort an array of pointers to struct by one of the values.

Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out why this doesn't work. the compare function seems right to me, I am wondering if something is wrong with unsigned ints.

the **struct**:

```
typedef struct node{

    unsigned int identifier;
    unsigned int value;

}Node;
```

the **compare function**:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b){
    
    Node* sum_a = (Node*)a;
    Node* sum_b = (Node*)b;
    if(sum_a->value > sum_b->value)return 1;
    if(sum_a->value == sum_b->value)return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

the **code** I have used to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 20
Node* init_node(Node* ins_node,unsigned int identifier,unsigned int value){
    ins_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ins_node->identifier=identifier;
    ins_node->value=value;
    return ins_node;
}
int main (){

    Node*curr_node;
    Node*box[SIZE];
    box[0]=init_node(curr_node,27,9999);
    for(int i = 1;i<SIZE;i++){
        box[i]=init_node(curr_node,i,SIZE*2-i);
    }

    qsort(box,SIZE,sizeof(Node*),compare);

    printf("\nsorted:\n");
    for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d/%d\n",box[i]->identifier,box[i]->value);
    }
    
}
```

the **output** which is clearly not sorted:

```
sorted:
27/9999
1/39
2/38
3/37
4/36
5/35
6/34
7/33
8/32
9/31
10/30
11/29
12/28
13/27
14/26
15/25
16/24
17/23
18/22
19/21
```

Thanks to u all in advance :)

Comment: Yeah it is. It's sorted in descending order of value. Big ones come before smaller ones. Reverse the `return 1` and `return -1` in your compare func to sort in ascending order. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep it's not. the order descending u see is given by the definition of the test case I have used if u swap the returns the output is the same. sry for the misleading testcase :)

Comment: 9999, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21 - You tell me then. Which one's out of order?! What was the initial order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison function is invalid and invokes undefined behavior. The elements of the array are passed by reference to the function. So you need to define the function at least like

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b){
    
    Node* sum_a = *(Node**)a;
    Node* sum_b = *(Node**)b;
    if(sum_a->value > sum_b->value)return 1;
    if(sum_a->value == sum_b->value)return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Also the first parameter of the function init_node is not used.

Define the function like

```
Node* init_node(unsigned int identifier,unsigned int value){
    Node *ins_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ins_node->identifier=identifier;
    ins_node->value=value;
    return ins_node;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem :) may I ask u why ```(Node*)a``` doesn't work while ```*(Node**)```a does?

Comment: @MrCont Elements of your array have the pointer type Node *. They are passed to the comparison function by reference that is like for example &box[i]. So the type of the passed to the function expression is Node *  *.